# Splitting a persistant set

Tags: grails, split, set, persistent

I have used the code

```
def a = Domain.list()
```

when i write in `log.info a.class` it tell me to be a persistant set. I had been trying to get element at a index but couldn't do with

```
a.toArray()
log.info a[0]
```

How do I split my object returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toArray()` returns new array, it not modifying object in place, try:

```
a = a.toArray()
log.info a[0]
```

Btw, you can use:

```
def a = Domain.list() as List
log.info a[0]
```

PS are you sure that you're getting `Set` instead of `List`?